# How do addEventListener and attachEvent works? Keydown and Keyup is not working properly

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I wrote a code snippet for "shift key" keydown and keyup events for the mozilla but it is not working as I expect.
Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Testing Page</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var key_capslock = 0;
var key_shift = 0;

function print1(){ window.alert("shift status" + key_shift);}
function print2(){ window.alert("shift status" + key_shift);}
function keyset(evt){
  evt.preventDefault();
  if(evt.keyCode == 16){
     if(key_shift == 0 ){key_shift = 1; evt.stopPropagation();}
     else {key_shift = 0; evt.stopPropagation();}
  }
print1();
return;
}
function keyrelease(evt){
   evt.preventDefault();
   if(evt.keyCode == 16){
      if(key_shift == 0 ){key_shift = 1; evt.stopPropagation();}
      else {key_shift = 0; evt.stopPropagation();}
   }
print2();
return;
}

function init(){
document.body.setAttribute("contentEditable", true);
document.body.addEventListener("keydown", keyset, false);
document.body.addEventListener("keyup", keyrelease, false);
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
<br>
<body>
</html>
```

Steps: 1. Press the shift key (keydown and keyup events occur).
       2. alert comes with shift status (print1 function runs). I click that.
      Expected: alert should come with shift status (print2 function should run).
      Actual: print2 function does not run.

If I press shift key second time then print2 function runs.
I don't understand how the mozilla handling addEventListener function.
Can someone please help me to resolve this issue? I don't want to use any third party framework to resolve this issue (jquery, dojo etc).

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Your code is actually fine, but the alert message takes the focus from the browser, preventing it from detecting `keyup`.

If you change the functions to write to a div, for instance, you will see that both functions work:

http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/VqNvG/

Although, I don't understand this code:

```
if(key_shift == 0 ){key_shift = 1; evt.stopPropagation();}
 else {key_shift = 0; evt.stopPropagation();}
```

If you are in `keyset`, key_shift should always be 1 it seems, rather than toggling:

```
function keyset(evt){
  evt.preventDefault();
  if(evt.keyCode == 16){
     key_shift = 1;
     evt.stopPropagation();
  }
  print1();
  return;
}
function keyrelease(evt){
   evt.preventDefault();
   if(evt.keyCode == 16){
      key_shift = 0;
      evt.stopPropagation();
   }
   print2();
   return;
}
```